# Accessing an object from another object

Tags: perl, oop, parameter-passing, encapsulation

I would like you to share your experience on the matter of using some common object by different components of a library (or an application). I'd like to understand, which practice is better, which way is more "ecological".

Let's imagine that we have some complex library that consists of a bunch of classes: `Library`, `Library::Foo`, `Library::Foo::Bar` and many other ones. An application that uses the library initializes a `Library`-classed object, at some stage this object initializes some quantity of `Library::Foo`-classed objects, they initialize `Library::Foo::Bar`-classed objects and so on.

And now let's imagine that there is the `Library::Logger` class that is being used by all components. It's being initialized only once by the constructor of the `Library` class and all other sub-classes need it for their logging purposed.

The question is: how to let them all have the reference to this object?

I see the following ways to acheive it:

#### Passing it to the constructor

When a `Library`-based object initializes a `Library::Foo`-classed object, it passes the reference to the logger to the newly-created object as a parameter:

```
$self->_set_logger(Library::Logger->new());
my $logger = $self->_get_logger;
my $foo = Library::Foo->new(logger => $logger);
```

So the `Library::Foo`-classed object could get the logger and even pass it to a `Library::Foo::Bar`-classed object when it's needed:

```
my $logger = $self->_get_logger;
my $bar = Library::Foo::Bar(logger => $logger);
```

#### Accessing it as a method

When a `Library`-based object initializes the Library::Foo-based object, it passes the reference *to itself* to the newly-created object:

```
$self->_set_logger(Library::Logger->new());
my $foo = Library::Foo->new(papa => $self);
```

So the `Library::Foo`-based object could access the logger this way:

```
$my logger = $self->_get_papa->_get_logger;
my $bar = Library::Foo::Bar(papa => $self);
```

It breaks encapsulation, but it also lets the `Library::Foo`-based object to get other data from its "papa".

#### Using a global variable

Also we can store the reference to the logger in some global variable, so any other object could access it this way:

```
$logger = $Library::_LOGGER;
```

Well, it really sucks, I know... :)

#### ...

So, what do you think, which way seems to be better? What alternative way would you propose? How do you solve this problem for yourself? Would you pass the data to the "child" manually or would you let it to get the data from the "parent"?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Asking what we think is asking for an opinion, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You have written a very high-quality post, which is great, but you need to [edit] and reword it to make it on-topic.

Comment: As of what do I prefer... it depends on how many of those modules there are. You can make it a global variable, and maybe abstract that into a role that all objects that should have a logger share. That way you can easily change where the logger object comes from. Or you can make the logger class be a singleton. Inside of the class, you can just define a `my $obj` or whatever on the outermost scope, so that it's lexical to the file. Then have the constructor assign it the first round, and just return it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer to your problem. It realy depends on your exact use-case. If (just guessing) you only want to have exactly one Logger in your Library, I think using the software pattern of a "singleton" might exactly fit. E.g.

```
package Library::Logger;
use strict;

my $logger;

sub new {
    unless ($logger) {
       .... initializing $logger ...
    }
    return $logger;
}
```

and in each of your sublclasses you can access it by

```
Library::Logger->new()->...
```

HTH
Georg

Comment: Thank you, Georg. Singletons are great, but I rather need it to be initialized once per a `Library`-classed object than once per an application at all. So the question is not how to make sure that this object is being initialized only once, but the question is how to let other objects use it. Is it better to _give_ them the reference (e.g. on the initialization stage) or is it better to _let them get_ the reference (perhaps by calling a method that is being provided by some object that "knows" where the logger's object is).

Comment: Again this depends of where the logger lives. You only pass a logger, if you might pass a different one in a different context. If you already pass an object that "knows" your logger, use that. And if you consider using a global variable, use a singleton Class instead.